# Detect size of taskbar buttons

Tags: windows, typescript, electron

Is there a way detect size of taskbar buttons (small or large) on Windows 7,10?

There is a registry that could be used `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarSmallIcons` but I don't know if electron provides ability read registry

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 methods, they all would query the registry key on your application load, and you could send the data either via IPC from your main to the render process or as preload script in the render process only.

1. Spawn a process that executes [reg query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query) or similiar and you then parse the result string. I personally would do it via `Get-ItemProperty` in powershell. (simple)

> This should return you the value as a JSON

```
 Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name TaskbarSmallIcons | Select-Object -Property TaskbarSmallIcons | ConvertTo-Json
```

3. Create/Use a native node module to call the Windows API (harder)